# Incorrectly parsed ReturnJSON method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, linq

This method

```
var fListItems = db.FListItems.Include(f => f.FList)
                              .Include(f => f.Item)
                              .GroupBy(g => new { g.Item.Name, g.FList.Title })
                              .Select(lg =>
                               new FListItemsViewModel
                               {
                                   Title = lg.Key.Title,
                                   ItemStat = new ItemStat
                                   {
                                       Name = lg.Key.Name,
                                       NameCount = lg.Count(),
                                       NameSum = lg.Sum(w => w.Score),
                                       NameAverage = lg.Average(w => w.Score)
                                   }
                               });
```

returns this JSON

```
[
    {
        Title: "Animals",
        ItemStat: {
            Name: "Cat",
            NameCount: 2,
            NameSum: 8,
            NameAverage: 4
        }
    },
    {
        Title: "Animals",
        ItemStat: {
            Name: "Dog",
            NameCount: 1,
            NameSum: 5,
            NameAverage: 5
        }
    }
]
```

but I'd like it to return this JSON:

```
[
    {
        Title: "Animals",
        ItemStats: [
            {
                Name: "Cat",
                NameCount: 2,
                NameSum: 8,
                NameAverage: 4
            },
            {
                Name: "Dog",
                NameCount: 1,
                NameSum: 5,
                NameAverage: 5
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Can anybody suggest how to do this? Here's the viewmodel:

```
public class FListItemsViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ItemStat ItemStat { get; set; }
}
public class ItemStat
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NameCount { get; set; }
    public int NameSum { get; set; }
    public double NameAverage { get; set; }
}
```

Rather than `GroupBy` `Title` and `Name` in the same clause, could it be better to re-write my query with two seperate `GroupBy`s?

Progress based on Rahul's answer:

```
[
    {
        Title: "Animals",
        ItemStat: [
            {
                Name: "Cat",
                NameCount: 2,
                NameSum: 8,
                NameAverage: 4
            },
            {
                Name: "Cat",
                NameCount: 2,
                NameSum: 8,
                NameAverage: 4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Title: "Animals",
        ItemStat: [
            {
                Name: "Dog",
                NameCount: 1,
                NameSum: 5,
                NameAverage: 5
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the output I'm after so I want to say this is the answer.

Unless anybody can spot anything untoward?

```
 var fListItems = db.FListItems.Include(f => f.FList)
                               .Include(f => f.Item)
                               .GroupBy(g => g.FaveList.Title)
                               .Select(lg =>
                                   new FListItemsViewModel
                                       {
                                           Title = lg.Key,
                                           ItemStat = lg.GroupBy(x => x.Item.Name)
                                                        .Select(x => new ItemStat
                                                            {
                                                                Name = x.Key,
                                                                NameCount = x.Count(),
                                                                NameSum = x.Sum(w => w.Score),
                                                                NameAverage = x.Average(w => w.Score)
                                                            }).ToList()
                                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

For this Firstly you need to change your ViewModel as ::

```
public class FListItemsViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<ItemStat> ItemStat { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can access the result in Enumerable format as::

```
var fListItems = db.FListItems.Include(f => f.FList)
                              .Include(f => f.Item)
                              .GroupBy(g => new { g.Item.Name, g.FList.Title })
                              .Select(lg =>
                               new FListItemsViewModel
                               {
                                   Title = lg.Key.Title,
                                   ItemStat =lg.Select(x=> new ItemStat
                                   {
                                       Name = x.Key.Name,
                                       NameCount = x.Count(),
                                       NameSum = x.Sum(w => w.Score),
                                       NameAverage = x.Average(w => w.Score)
                                   }).ToList()
                               });
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I'm seeing errors on these lines: `Title = lg.Key.Title` - "string does not contain a definition for Title...". And `Name = x.Name` - "Project.Models.FlistItem does not contain a definition for Name..." Also, will this still group the names as well as the titles? Thanks again

Comment: Many thanks again. I've updated my question to show the result I'm now getting. It's not quite as I'd hoped. I've added another `Cat` to show how although the grouping is correct, the groups are duplicated by the count number